# I want to create advanced search using ajax codeigniter per categories

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am making a search function with codeigniter.
The search needs to show the search result per category, when I click the categories it will be show the real result (detail, with the image).
For the search I made a form:

```
Title:
Author:
Publisher:
Year Published
ISBN : 

<btn submit>
```

if I submit it will show the URL like this:

```
http:readynew1.8/advancedsearch/search?advTitle=diktat&advAuthor=&advPublisher=&advYear=&advISBN=
===========================================
Search Result
==========================================
Book 6
Journal 4
```

The code is fine until here.

The problem is that when I click the category book I cant get the data that was sent from the input form.
If I use `$this->input->get();` and send it as parameter to my function `showdetails(Title,ISBN);`
the parameter cant be null, and also I cant find any book with title that contains a comma,
so I think I need to get the input data with ajax with form.serialize but I still don't get the data from input text.

Can anyone help me?

code search controller that I get for categories

```
public function search()
{   
    $AssetTitle = $this->input->POST("advTitle");
    $Author = $this->input->POST('advAuthor');
    $Publisher = $this->input->POST('advPublisher');
    $Year = $this->input->POST('advYear');
    $ISBN = $this->input->POST('advISBN');
    $result = $this->advanced_model->search_result();
    $data['temp']=$this->advanced_model->getcountadvanced();    
    $data["CatId"]=$this->viewbook_model->getCategory();
    $x=0;


    if(count($result) > 0){
            foreach($result AS $d)
            {
                $data['searchresult'][$x] = array(
                    'CategoryAssetName' => $d['CategoryAssetName'],
                    'CategoryAssetId' => $d['CategoryAssetId'],
                    'AssetTitle' => $d['Bibli'],
                    'Author' => $d['Bibli'],
                    'Publisher' => $d['PublisherId'],
                    'Year' => $Year,
                    'ISBN' => $ISBN
                );
                $x++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
        $data['searchresult'] = array();
        }

    $page_content["page_title"] = "Advanced Search";
    $page_content["title"] = "Advanced Search";
    $page_content["icon_title"] = "search";

    $menu_params["current_navigable"] = "AdvancedSearch";
    $menu_params["sub_current_navigable"] = "";

    $page_content["menu"] = $this->load->view("main_menu", $menu_params, true);
    $page_content["content"] = $this->load->view("advancedsearch", $data, true);
    $page_content["navmenu"] = $this->load->view("nav_menu",$data, true);

    $this->load->view("template/main_template", $page_content);

}
```

my function to get details:

function test($CategoryAssetId="",$AssetTitle="",$Author="",$Publisher="",$Year="",$ISBN=""){

```
    $data = $this->input->post();
    echo $data;




    $data["CatId"]=$this->viewbook_model->getCategory();

        /*$AssetTitle = $this->input->GET('advTitle');
        $Author = $this->input->GET('advAuthor');
        $Publisher = $this->input->GET('advPublisher');
        $Year = $this->input->GET('advYear');
        $ISBN = $this->input->GET('advISBN');

        */
        /*echo $AssetTitle.'<br />';
        echo $Author.'<br />';
        echo $Publisher.'<br />';
        echo $Year.'<br />';
        echo $ISBN.'<br />';*/

        $AssetTitleEx = explode("-",$AssetTitle);
        $AssetTitleIm = implode(" ",$AssetTitleEx);

        //echo $Author;
        $AuthorEx = explode("-",$Author);
        $AuthorIm = implode(" ",$AuthorEx);
        //echo $AuthorIm;

        $PublisherEx = explode("-",$Publisher);
        $PublisherIm = implode(" ",$PublisherEx);



    $result = $this->advanced_model->searchresult($CategoryAssetId,$AssetTitleIm,$AuthorIm,$PublisherIm,$Year,$ISBN);   
    //print_r($result);
    //echo count($result);
    $x=0;

    if(count($result) > 0){
            foreach($result AS $d)
            {
                $data['tem'][$x] = array(
                    'categoryassetid' =>$d["CategoryAssetId"],
                    'AssetTitle' => $d["AssetTitle"],
                    'AssetSubtitle' => $d["AssetSubtitle"],
                    'PublisherName' => $d['PublisherName'],
                    'PublishYear' => $d['PublishYear'],
                    'MainAuthor' => $d['MainAuthor'],
                    'ISBN' => $d['ISBN'],
                    'Photo' => $d['Photo'],
                    'Bibli' => $d['Bibli'],
                    'CategoryAssetName' => $d['CategoryAssetName'],
                    'Description' => $d['Description']
                );
                $x++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
        $data['tem'] = array();
        }


    /*$page_content["page_title"] = "Advanced Search";
    $page_content["title"] = "Advanced Search";
    $page_content["icon_title"] = "search";

    $menu_params["current_navigable"] = "AdvancedSearch";
    $menu_params["sub_current_navigable"] = "";

    $page_content["menu"] = $this->load->view("main_menu", $menu_params, true);
    $page_content["content"] = $this->load->view("advancedsearch", $data, true);
    $page_content["navmenu"] = $this->load->view("nav_menu",$data, true);

    $this->load->view("template/main_template", $page_content);*/
}
```

}

please help me if you have another idea..

Comment: input->get() & input->post() are all small letters, You don't foreach in your controller, And you shouldn't extract ->get() & ->post() in your model, you pass these from controller, returning result is good enough so your foreach isn't doing anything special.

Comment: Your post isn't very clear, please provide the table structure and explain what you want to do.